# Xamarin.Forms How to add Behaviors in code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, behavior

What I am trying to achieve is limiting the input of an Entry field to two character via code and not XAML

This can be achieved in XAML using the below:

```
<Entry.Behaviors>
        <local:NumberValidatorBehavior x:Name="ageValidator" />
        <local:MaxLengthValidator  MaxLength="2"/>
```

I assume I will need to do something like this but I'm not quite sure how to add the required behaviour property

```
entry.Behaviors.Add(new MyBehavior())
```

## **Edit Answer**

After adding the MaxLengthValidator class listed below and calling it using the proposed method by @Rui Marinho my code is working as expected.

```
public class MaxLengthValidator : Behavior<Entry>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MaxLengthProperty = BindableProperty.Create("MaxLength", typeof(int), typeof(MaxLengthValidator), 0);

    public int MaxLength
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MaxLengthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxLengthProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged += bindable_TextChanged;
    }

    private void bindable_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewTextValue.Length > 0 && e.NewTextValue.Length > MaxLength)
            ((Entry)sender).Text = e.NewTextValue.Substring(0, MaxLength);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged -= bindable_TextChanged;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
entry.Behaviors.Add(new MaxLengthValidator { MaxLength = 2 });
```

Comment: The type or namespace MaxLengthValidator cannot be found when using the above

Comment: I assume you have MaxLengthValidator behavior class right? You should jus need to pull the namespace

Comment: I was indeed missing the MaxLengthValidator class. After adding the class and referencing it my behavior is working as expected. Thanks for the help